# Session variable can't be updated

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, session, session-variables

Whenever i try to update a session variable that has been previously entered it won't update.

Heres an example on what i'm talking about:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Test"] != null) 
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Session["Test"].ToString();
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Test"] = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

So when i click the button the first time, the textbox will be updated. But when i edit the text and click the button again, the textbox just reverts to what it was the first time i.e doesn't update. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Which Session Variable you are trying to upate

Comment: TextBox1 will always have the Session["Box"] value which you are not updating anywhere in the code so it will not update

Comment: why dont you just drop the session.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So when i click the button the first time, the textbox will be
>   updated. But when i edit the text and click the button again, the
>   textbox just reverts to what it was the first time

I believe it's because you are doing just exactly as that:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Test"] != null) 
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Session["Test"].ToString();
    }
}
```

In that code you have you should be checking if the page load is caused by a post back (click of a button). So you should be doing this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack && Session["Test"] != null) 
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Session["Test"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["Test"] != null && Session["Test"].ToString().Length > 0)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Session["Test"].ToString();
        }
    }
    Session["Test"] = string.Empty;
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Session["Test"] = TextBox1.Text;
  }
```

This is tested code.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {            
        Session["Test"] = "";           
    }
    if (Session["Test"] != null)
    {    
        Session["Test"] = ASPxTextBox1.Text;            
    }
}


protected void ASPxButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ASPxTextBox1.Text = Session["Test"].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You page is posted back thats why it is taking previous value as you have written

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["Test"] != null) 
    {
        TextBox1.Text = Session["Test"].ToString();
    }
}
```

int this code the text box text will be restored with the previous value which you entered before,
so your code should be

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

if(!IsPostBack)
{
if (Session["Test"] != null) 
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Session["Test"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Session["Test"] != null)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = Session["Test"].ToString();
        }
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Test"] = TextBox1.Text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the Page_Load event before the Button Click, so your Page_Load is overwriting the value of TextBox1.Text with the previous value in the Session.  That is why it never changes after the first time it is set.

Check that you are not responding to a post on Page_Load like this:

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     if (!IsPostBack)
     {
        TextBox1.Text = (Session["Test"] ?? "").ToString();
     }
  }

  protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     Session["Test"] = TextBox1.Text;
  }
```

With that said, you probably want to avoid using the Session altogether if it can be helped.